# EXTJS 4 : GoogleMap SetZoom Error

Tags: google-maps

### html Header

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZx1jmE9yB533ED9suD13buyd0pEfmTzI&sensor=false"></script>
```

i get the error with:

```
TypeError: map123.setZoom is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

map123.setZoom(15);
```

this is my sample code
http://jsfiddle.net/anthor/4aAKL/1/
p/s:you can try on jsfiddle,nothing happen with SetZoom when clicked the marker

why?how to solve this problem?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ext JS?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli nothing,but i use EXT js can't work with this code,please check my code with the link above